# localStorage Usage optimization

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, javascript-objects

In a simple Todo Application, suppose we have an array of todo list that should be stored in localStorage.

```
var todoList=[{id:1,text:'todo1'},{id:2,text:'todo2'}]
```

to store the array in locaStorage it has to be stringified, and stored as Object key value.

The Question is, suppose I have an array of todos with 10000 items, do I have to stringify the whole array each time I store the array? is there such a way to only store the changes, and merge it with current item ?

I Have tried modifying the localStorage item directly like:

```
//this will replace last occurence of ] with new stringified object + ]
localStorage.todos.(/]$/, "new stringified object"+']')
```

but it doesn't modify the original object in localStorage, in other words you can only set localStorage items using setItem() method.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to treat `localStorage` as a persistence mechanism only, and ideally not a place to keep data that you're actively working on. Behind the scenes, it's just a key/value store, where the value is always a string, so stringifying the entire value is unavoidable.

Frankly, the performance impact of stringifying an array of 10,000 items is negligible (An *O(n)* operation), so I wouldn't worry about it anyway, but if you want to squeeze every last bit of performance out of your application, then I'd only persist your data when necessary, and not after every modification. Manipulate your TO-DO list with an in-memory copy, then stringify it when you're done.